# Qmail and setting up a mail forwarder

Tags: smtp, email, email-server

We have a set of servers that are isolated from our main network, they are an island from our corporate network. At the moment we have to get relay rules added each time we want to send mails from one of these servers to the outside world. So our plan was to build a dedicated server on this Island and have all mail directed to it, which would relay onto to Corp.

A second advantage of this was to allow us to build plugins to analyse and parse the mails. All of the mails are errors and informational messages about our apps.

My first thoughts on this was to use Qmail as I built a system like this years ago (10 years) when I was in a different company. My colleague also had experience with Qmail so that seemed the obvious choice. The problem is we have both been reading about Qmail and there seems to have been no work done on this in years. This is seems quite strange.

So the questions we have are;

- Is Qmail still support and has it any sort of active community
- Leaving sendmail aside (we don't consider this a choice) is there a Qmail like MTA
- Would I better of using something else e.g. postfix.
- Where is the best place to find out what is going on in the MTA world (vague I know)

Or am I making too much of this and should go ahead and install something even tough it seems to be over 10 years old with very little change.

I hope this is not too long winded but any help would be much appreciated.

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at indimail based on a modified qmail. I have not used it in production but have been following it's progress for some time and it is being actively developed.

Answer (score 0):

We recently replaced some aging qmail servers.  Initially we planned to continue using qmail on a newer OS, but ended up switching to postfix since it's actively maintained and very easy to configure.  You may want to consider it.